# Default value of a variable passed from controller with ng-init in angular text box not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

I want to display default value of an input text box in edit form using ng-init but I cannot make it no matter what I did.

Here is what I wrote.

In controller:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('users.php').then(function (result) {  
   $scope.data = result.data;

   $scope.username = $scope.data.username;
   $scope.email = $scope.data.email;
   $scope.phone = $scope.data.phone;
});
```

In view:

```
   <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
       <span class="input-label">Username</span>
       <input type="text" ng-model="formData.username" placeholder="Email" ng-init="formData.email={{username}}">
   </label>
   <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Phone</span>
             <input type="text" ng-model="formData.phone" placeholder="0815********" ng-init="formData.phone='{{phone}}'">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Email</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="formData.email" placeholder="" ng-init="formData.email='{{email}}'">
    </label>
```

I also tried to write `ng-init="formData.email={{email}}"` and `ng-init="formData.email=email"` but still not working.

Comment: don't use ng-init..... set your ng-model in controller

Comment: @CharlieNg how to do that? sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: what is formData? where did you declare it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your main problem is setting that ng-init, first if you want to set it like that you shouldn't use `{{ scopevar }}` when you are inside of ng-init, but just `scopevar`.

But even then, there is no reason to do it like you're trying.
Once you set up data model on field, it will update automatically when you get data - angular will do everything for you, just set it up like in example below:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('users.php').then(function (result) {  
   $scope.formData = result.data;
});
});
```

And remove ng-inits from your code.

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
       <span class="input-label">Username</span>
       <input type="text" ng-model="formData.username" placeholder="Email" >
   </label>
   <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Phone</span>
             <input type="text" ng-model="formData.phone" placeholder="0815********" >
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Email</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="formData.email" placeholder="">
    </label>
```

Also, I made a fiddle with simplified example.
https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/9mqz8drh/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
   <span class="input-label">Username</span>
   <input type="text" ng-model="formData.username" placeholder="Email" >
```

Remove ng-init from your code. Keep your controller like this

```
   .controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('users.php').then(function (result) {  
   $scope.formData = result.data;
});
});
```